# Undefined reference to vector declared in a different source file used in an "if" statement

Tags: c++

I've created a source file that contains a number of data structures (maps, vector, array). Its header file is `#included` in the main-file.

The main file looks like this:

```
#include "reachability.h" //Where monkey() and vector<int> int_req are declared

main()
{
    monkey(int_req); // Calling monkey(int_req) here is OK! Bar is visible

    ... 

    ifstream fp("foo.txt"); 
    if(fp.is_open())
    {
       std::string line; 
       while( getline(fp,line) )
       {
           monkey(int_req); //'int_req' is an undefined reference!
       }
    }
}
```

And **reachability.h**

```
#ifndef REACHABILITY_H
#define REACHABILITY_H

extern std::vector<int> int_req; 

void monkey(std::vector<int> feces); 

#endif
```

And **reachability.cc**

```
std::vector<int> int_req; 

void monkey(std::vector<int> thrown_obj)
{ 
   ... //Iteration and dereferencing of "thrown_obj"
}
```

I've accessed data structures that are declared in `reachability.cc` in a for-loop in the scope of main and *that* was fine. Something wonky is happening in this if-statement though.

Compiler Error:

```
lab1.o: In function `main':
/home/ubuntu/workspace/ECE597/Lab1/lab1.cc:105: undefined reference to `int_req'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Edited: reachability.cc is included in compiliation:

```
elusivetau:~/XXXX/XXXX/XXXX $ g++ lab1.cc parser.cc gate.cc reachability.cc -o run
/tmp/ccJK4O9q.o: In function `main':
lab1.cc:(.text+0x489): undefined reference to `int_req'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Edited: makefile for this program:

```
all: lab1.o parser.o gate.o reachability.o
    g++ -g lab1.o parser.o gate.o reachability.o -o run

lab1.o: lab1.cc 
    g++ -g -c lab1.cc 

parser.o: parser.cc 
    g++ -g -c parser.cc 

gate.o: gate.cc
    g++ -g -c gate.cc

reachability.o: reachability.cc
    g++ -g -c reachability.cc

clean: 
    rm *o run
```

Comment: If it says "undefined reference" it's a linker error, and it doesn't refer just to the line inside the `if`. Probably you are not linking in `src1.cpp`.

Comment: Perhaps. The statement I used to compile is attached in the edit.

Comment: From the message, I can confirm that it is a linker error (`ld` is the linker). I don't see `Src1.cpp` on that line, but maybe it has actually another name? You should really use real names and real code, otherwise it becomes impossible to understand what's going on.

Comment: Oops sorry it is an alias for "reachability.cpp". I will use real names next time. 'bar' is a vector<int> in "reachability.cpp"/"src1.cpp"

Comment: `reachability.cpp` or `.cc`? Please fix the whole thing up in the question body, it's becoming very confusing... By the way, maybe `int_req` is in a namespace (or is `static`) in the `.cpp` but not in the `.h`?

Comment: Names of files should be consistent now. 

I'm not sure what you mean by "in a namespace". I've made no `using namespace std;`  statement in any files. 

Also, no `static` specifier was used in either the .cc nor .h file.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever it is, you're not giving us the correct information.

I added includes and removed non-code to make this compile. And voila, it also links:

test.cpp:

```
#include "reachability.h" //Where monkey() and vector<int> int_req are declared
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

main()
{
    monkey(int_req); // Calling monkey(int_req) here is OK! Bar is visible

    std::ifstream fp("foo.txt");
    if(fp.is_open())
    {
       std::string line;
       while( getline(fp,line) )
       {
           monkey(int_req); //'int_req' is an undefined reference!
       }
    }
}
```

reachability.h:

```
#ifndef REACHABILITY_H
#define REACHABILITY_H

#include <vector>

extern std::vector<int> int_req;

void monkey(std::vector<int> feces);

#endif
```

reachability.cpp:

```
#include "reachability.h"

std::vector<int> int_req;

void monkey(std::vector<int> thrown_obj)
{
}
```

This compiles and links just fine. You are leading us on a wild goose chase by not bothering to create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)